# Time series analysis For loop Python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, prediction, forecasting

I'm trying to automate the process of predicting (1) the total demand of each State and (2) demand of each Customer in each State. The statistic method applied is Moving Average. The predict time is 1 month ahead.The data is imported from an excel sheet having 5 columns: Customer, State, Product, Quantity, Order Date. The excel file can be found via the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JlIqWl8bfyJ3Io01Zx088GIAC6rRuCa8/view?usp=sharing

One Customer can be associated with different States, for example, Aaron Bergman can buy Chair, Art, Phone from stores in Washington, Texas and Oklahoma. The other customers has the same purchase behaviour. For (1) I tried using For loop, but it did not work. The error is Order_Date not in index

```
df = pd.read_excel("Sales_data.xlsx")
State_Name = df.State.unique()
Customer_Name = df.Customer.unique()

for x in State_Name:
   df = df[['Order_Date', 'Quantity']]
   df['Order_Date'].min(), df['Order_Date'].max()
   df.isnull().sum()

   df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Order_Date, format= '%D-%M-%Y %H:%m')
   df.index = df.Timestamp
   df = df.resample('MS').sum()

   rolling_mean = df.Quantity.rolling(window=10).mean()
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation; it is a matter of right vs wrong in Python. You do not seem to use `x` anywhere in the loop. Is that intentional?

Comment: Also, you are continually attempting to update `df`. So on second pass, `df` is not same as csv data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider turning `for` loop lines into a defined method and call it with `groupby` to return time series. Also, heed best practices in `pandas`:

- Avoid [referencing columns as attributes with period qualifiers](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data). Instead, use bracketing `[]`.
- Avoid `[]` with a list for [column subsetting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-with-list-with-missing-labels-is-deprecated). Instead, use `reindex`.

```py
def rollmean_func(df):
   # BETTER COLUMN SUBSET
   df = df.reindex(['Order_Date', 'Quantity'], axis='columns')  

   # BETTER COLUMN ASSIGNMENT
   df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order_Date'], format= '%D-%M-%Y %H:%m')  
   df.index = df['Timestamp']

   df = df.resample('MS').sum()
   rolling_mean = df['Quantity'].rolling(window=10).mean()
  
   return rolling_mean
```

States Level

```py
state_rollmeans = df.groupby(['State']).apply(rollmean_func)
state_rollmeans
# State      Timestamp 
# Alabama    2014-04-01     NaN
#            2014-05-01     NaN
#            2014-06-01     NaN
#            2014-07-01     NaN
#            2014-08-01     NaN
# ...
# Wisconsin  2017-09-01    10.6
#            2017-10-01     7.5
#            2017-11-01     9.7
#            2017-12-01    12.3
# Wyoming    2016-11-01     NaN
# Name: Quantity, Length: 2070, dtype: float64
```

Customers Level

```py
customer_rollmeans = df.groupby(['Customer_Name']).apply(rollmean_func)
customer_rollmeans
# Customer_Name       Timestamp 
# Aaron Bergman       2014-02-01    NaN
#                     2014-03-01    NaN
#                     2014-04-01    NaN
#                     2014-05-01    NaN
#                     2014-06-01    NaN
# ...
# Zuschuss Donatelli  2017-02-01    1.2
#                     2017-03-01    0.7
#                     2017-04-01    0.7
#                     2017-05-01    0.0
#                     2017-06-01    0.3
# Name: Quantity, Length: 26818, dtype: float64
```

Comment: If `window` has different values `for x in range (2,10)`, then `rolling_mean = df['Quantity'].rolling(window=x).mean()`. It should give 8 different results, however, the `state_rollmeans = df.groupby(['State']).apply(rollmean_func)` will give the average of the 8 results instead. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Customer level, take Aaron Bergman  as an example, corresponding State includes Washington, Texas and Oklahoma.. So there should be 3 forecasts associated with the name Aaron Bergman, not the total demand in those 3 States for Aaron Bergman

Comment: So you need state AND customer grouping? If so, add both in `groupby`. And yes, this solution returns one window at a time. You need to adjust window in function and call `groupby().apply()` for each window. Combining will yield many NaNs due to different window sizes.

Comment: BTW, this solution simply resolves your error with existing code. You do not post desired results or structure. I assume nothing else only show a way to save results from iterations and avoid `for` loop.